# With the following settings shown here, will there be any caching in Firefox?

Tags: browsers, cache, firefox, http, cache-control

```
browser.cache.disk.enable = false
browser.cache.memory.enable = false
network.http.use-cache = true
```

With the following settings above, will there be any caching in FF?

Does the disk.enable and memory.enable set to false override the true setting of use-cache?

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.use-cache

Thanks.

Comment: This might be better suited on [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: John, its also there.  http://superuser.com/questions/216552/with-the-following-settings-shown-here-will-there-be-any-caching-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

> Does the disk.enable and memory.enable set to false override the true setting of use-cache?

From the mozillaZine link, this would be a reasonable assumption. "This [use-cache] preference controls whether to cache files ... either in memory or on disk." - and if neither memory or disk caching is enabled then it would be reasonable to assume the page cannot be cached.

Comment: that's what i am thinking......thanks for the other post too.